# Conjecture inequality $\frac{\cosh(a)}{b+c}+\frac{\sinh(b)}{a+c}+\frac{\tanh(c)}{a+b}>e$

Tags: inequality, exponential-function, hyperbolic-functions

Let , $a\geq b \geq c >0$ such that $a+b+c=\frac{10}{11}$ then prove (or disprove) :

$$\frac{\cosh(a)}{b+c}+\frac{\sinh(b)}{a+c}+\frac{\tanh(c)}{a+b}>e$$

We cannot use Jensen's inequality as proof for this inequality since the functions $\cosh,\sinh,\tanh$ are differents .

The use of Am-Gm is inefficient . Moreover I have tried something like :

$$\frac{\cosh(a)}{b+c}+\frac{\sinh(b)}{a+c}+\frac{\tanh(c)}{a+b}>\frac{2e}{3}\Big(\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b}\Big)\geq e$$

Without success .

As a last resort I have tried power series but it's very ugly so not nice .

Update : 03/11/2020

I simplify a little bit the proof of user RiverLi  wich is a nice proof .

Due to convexity ($\cosh$ and $\sinh$) or concavity ($\tanh$) we have the following inequalities (always with the constraints above) :

$$\frac{\cosh(a)}{\frac{10}{11}-a}\geq f(a)=\frac{\cosh(\frac{10}{33})+(a-\frac{10}{33})\sinh(\frac{10}{33})}{\frac{10}{11}-a}$$

$$\frac{\sinh(b)}{\frac{10}{11}-b}\geq g(b)=\frac{\sinh(\frac{10}{33})+(b-\frac{10}{33})\cosh(\frac{10}{33})}{\frac{10}{11}-b}$$

$$\frac{\tanh(c)}{\frac{10}{11}-c}\geq h(c)=\frac{c\tanh(\frac{10}{33})\frac{33}{10}}{\frac{10}{11}-c}$$

Now it's less harder to show that the function $f,g,h$ are convex and continue the proof of RiverLi .

Any idea is welcome!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where does the inequality come from? Is there any motivation for the constant $10/11$, or why the lower bound could be $e$? Or is this a random inequality that you came up with?

Comment: It looks true. With the given constraints *Mathematica* gives a minimum of $2.71926...$ for the given expression when $a=b=c=\frac{10}{33}$.

Comment: @RiverLi See my update I simplify a little bit your proof .Thanks again !

Comment: @ErikSatie  How to proceed in your setting?

Comment: @Raffaele Your minimum looks a lot like $e$ !

Comment: @K.defaoite But the minimum is not $e$. It is obvious that if the LHS is larger than $2.719$ then it is larger than $e$, tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.**

Let $f(a) = \frac{\cosh a}{10/11 - a}$,
$g(b) = \frac{\sinh b}{10/11 - b}$ and $h(c) = \frac{\tanh c}{10/11 - c}$.

All $f, g, h$ are convex functions.

Then we have $f(a) \ge f(10/33) + f'(10/33)(a - 10/33)$,
$g(b) \ge g(10/33) + g'(10/33)(b-10/33)$
and $h(c) \ge h(10/33) + h'(10/33)(c-10/33)$.

It suffices to prove that
$$f(10/33) + f'(10/33)(a - 10/33)
+ g(10/33) + g'(10/33)(b-10/33) + h(10/33) + h'(10/33)(c-10/33) > \mathrm{e}.$$
Since $a\ge b\ge c$ and $f'(10/33) > g'(10/33) > h'(10/33)$, we have
$$\mathrm{LHS} \ge f(10/33) + g(10/33) + h(10/33) > \mathrm{e}.$$

Comment: Well I understand the last part if $a\geq b \geq \frac{10}{33}\geq c $ what about for the other case ?

Comment: Oh now I see for the other case we take $f'(\frac{10}{33})$ and it's complete . Thanks a lot !

Comment: @ErikSatie Under the conditions $a \ge b \ge c>0$ and $a+b+c = 10/11$, if we want to minimize $p_1a + p_2 b + p_3 c$ where $p_1 > p_2 > p_3$ are constants, then if $a > b $, we can adjust $a,b,c$ to $a-\epsilon, b + \epsilon, c$ to make the object smaller.

Comment: @ErikSatie You are welcome.

Comment: A last question is the smallest solution of : $\frac{\cosh(x)}{2x}+\frac{\sinh(x)}{2x}+\frac{\tanh(x)}{2x}=e$ Well know ?

Comment: @ErikSatie I have no idea.